Preview a pdf file and disabling the print button
I have a scenario to achieve my goal.
Convert the pdf file to image and then convert the image to base64 and pass it to my customize report viewer RDLC. However, based on my research it is necessary(?) to install or download from external (like nuget) to convert pdf to image but this is not applicable in my case. is there any built-in that i can convert the pdf file to image?
my only goal is when viewing the pdf file it is unable to print and download the file, only viewing.
